# Flutter google map place picker select address on specific zoom range only, search and customer image icon

Tags: flutter, google-maps, picker

I am currently in the process of developing a flutter mobile app for both iOS and Android platforms. I am trying to implement a Google map place picker to get the selected address info. The requirements needed is the ability to search for address, a specific zoom range to select an address from, a custom icon image, and getting the current position of user initially. However, the issue is that I could not find a package/documentation/implementation that provides me with these requirements.

Please if Could you provide me with a package/implementation/documentation to implement it in my app.

Thank you,